# IE7: Absolutely positioned Child Div with a negative CSS value for 'right'

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, css-position

I've been searching for hours:

I'm creating a small bar chart that i'm animating with jQuery.

I made the 'right' bar a child of the 'left' bar so they would always stay together as I animated their width properties.  Thus, the point they would never become separated during asynchronous animations. (I can animate the left bar and the right bar will just tag along..., since it's a child element)

I set the height/width of these two bars (with classes 'left' and 'right') with jQuery.  I animated the left bar's width property to size it.  To size the right bar, I animate the  CSS "right" property.

So here's the problem:  The right div is not visible with a negative value for 'right' (i tried 'margin-right,' too).  With positive values for 'right,' it politely appears inside its parent div (the left bar).  The moment I try to place it to the right of the 'left' bar, it goes away.

HELP!! :-O

It works gorgeously in IE8, and in everything else.

```
<div class="container" >
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="right"></div>
                </div>  
</div>


div.left{
    background-color:#93dbfb;
    overflow:visible;
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    left:0px;
}

div.right{
    background-color:#ffce42;
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    right:-300px;
}
```

(again, the height/width and right properties are all animated with jQuery)

** UPDATE **

I have already tried setting the position of the right-side bar using it's LEFT property (using the value left.width + [value]).   Same problem occurs.

Comment: Make a test case on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com). At the moment, it's *far too much work* to try to reproduce this. [Here's what I tried](http://jsfiddle.net/LyZZS/embedded/result/), and it looks the same in IE8 and IE8's IE7 mode.

Comment: Why have you accepted an answer if the problem isn't fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make this a comment but I can't seem to make them yet. Anyway, not sure if this works on IE7 but is this something like what you were trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/MnnyH/1/ I understand you were trying to make a chart, but this could easily be turned vertical.